# Se me ve un fondo negro cuando pasa de imagen el carousel de Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, imagen, carrusel

Como hago para que no se me vea un fondo negro entre imagen e imagen?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.carousel-caption{padding-bottom:80px;}

h2{font-size: 60px;}
p{padding:10px}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/img1.jpg');"></div>
     
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/img2.jpg');">
      
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/img3.jpg');"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias agregar una imagen de como se ve y como queres que se vea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira este ejemplo solo tendrias que ponerle un `backgropund:transparent;`

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

.carousel-caption{padding-bottom:80px;}

h2{font-size: 60px;}
p{padding:10px}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Título de la página</title>  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active fill">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-YjYKwYIGNjY/UPbJ0LUoGpI/AAAAAAAAAA8/_Y-uILD_q8M/s1600/img_informatica.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item fill">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rnOtrKp8wLQ/WCu_ZircmmI/AAAAAAAAASg/BSbEWXfhYsUcdlSm5_omA9LASTN7Ua1vQCLcB/s1600/curso-gratis-seguridad-informatica.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item fill">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.fusioninformatica.net/web/media/images/datacenter2.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probé con eso y ahora se queda un fondo blanco. Creo que no es ese el problema

Comment: copia y pega este mismo codigo, reemplasalo por el tuyo

Comment: Si ahí funciona, pero me cambia todo el responsive y ya no esta con el height 100%

Comment: a que te refieres ?

Comment: Lo que tu me pasaste es practicamente el carousel de bootsrtrap sin modificaciones por ejemplo en el responsive, las imagenes no se ven a pantalla completa (en el original mio si se ven).

Comment: mira la edicion que le hice al codigo ahora si las imagenes son responsive solo agregue la clase fill a los contenedores de las imagenes

Comment: Si le agrego la clase fill a los contenedores de las imágenes, no hace nada. Si se lo agrego a las imágenes quedan a pantalla completa pero estiradas y todas deformadas.
Perdón por estar haciéndote perder tanto tiempo con esto

Comment: estas seguro por que lo estoy probando y me funciona bien

Comment: Si, lo acabo de probar de vuelta y las imágenes en la versión responsive no cubren toda la pantalla del dispositivo. Quizá no me estabas entendiendo el problema que yo tenía.
Yo quiero que en la versión del celular las imágenes cubran el 100% del alto del celular

Comment: para ello usa los breakpoint de css osea los media querys

Comment: Ok intentare con eso.
Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda